# Save CGImageRef as PNG-8

Tags: objective-c, image, libpng

I'm wondering how to save a CGImageRef as a palette-based PNG-8 file.

I have the following code for PNG-24:

```
CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, properties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
```

Looking to convert this to PNG-8 now. If I do need to use libpng, how would you rewrite this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, no answers :) I believe the solution may be to use libpng but I haven't tried it yet. I'll mark this as the accepted answer for now, but if anyone can offer a good tip I'll gladly change it over!

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I ended up hacking apart https://github.com/pornel/pngquant to get it to accept CGImageRefs, and save PNG-8 files. It wasn't pretty. In the end, I actually switched to GIF (`kUTTypeGIF`) which ran a lot faster in my tests.

Comment: There's pngquant-derived [libimagequant](http://pngquant.org/lib) now, and it has `liq_set_speed()` option that lets you adjust speed/quality tradeoff (and with it even at highest speed you may get better quality than stock GIF writer achieves).